# background-size: cover. Existe alguma forma de acrescentar um valor em porcentagem?

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, sass, css-hover, scss

Quero adicionar um hover event que aumente ligeiramente o tamanho da imagem que estou usando de background, porém pra mantê-lo responsivo preciso do background-size:cover.

segue um trecho do código feito com scss:

```
&_container_row_{$i}{
        background: url('../img/BurgerImage{$i}.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        padding: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        @include imageTitle;
        transition: background-size 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    &_container_row_{$i}:hover{
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

gostaria de fazer algo do tipo no hover:

```
&_container_row_{$i}:hover{
        background-size: calc(cover + 15%);
    }
```

Agradeço desde já a quem puder responder!

Answer (score 0):

Cara no BG do próprio elemento vc não consegue, mas se vc colocar esse `bg` em um ***pseudo-elemento*** vc pode usar `transform: scale(1.15)` para aumentar em `15%`

Segue aqui um exemplo didático

```css
li {
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
li::before {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/100/100) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
li:hover{
  z-index: 2;
}
li:hover::before{
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>123</li>
  <li>123</li>
</ul>
```